# Русский аналог Open Server

Tags: openserver

Существует Open Server Panel — локальный веб-сервер для Windows. В нынешних условиях я задался вопросом, есть ли отечественные аналоги? Можете привести примеры? Самостоятельно искал, однако ничего не нашел. Буду признателен.

Comment: Аналогов другого плана в росии нет. А самое простое - это просто поставить всё необходимое ПО самому... для разработки всё равно нужно не так много

Comment: Ещё есть простой вариант: сделать для себя образ докера и потом его везде использовать

Answer (score -1):

Из популярных отечественных аналогов можно выделить [Denwer](http://www.denwer.ru/).

Хоть он на самом деле не является веб-сервером, но хранит в себе нужные связки Apache, PHP, MySQL и т.п.

Обновления выходили давно, поэтому тех же новых версий PHP вы в нем не найдете. Для этого лучше самостоятельно установить интерпретатор, или найти сборки сторонних разработчиков (на свой страх и риск).

Comment: Denwer - это не смешно.... рекомендовать то, что мертво...с PHP 5.3.....в нынешнее время-то

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Главное же показать аналоги. А на сколько они мертвы - другой вопрос :) "Невнятное ТЗ...".
Да и я же не рекомендую, просто констатирую факт, что аналог есть, просто никем не используется